# Pass raw string to action attribute as a parameter

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

In my application I have something like this:

```
<h:commandButton value="Some Value" action="#{outcome}" />
```

Somewhere I want to pass a param to the outcome param:

```
<ui:param name="outcome" value="index" />
```

But I get the error:

```
action="#{outcome}": Identity 'outcome' does not reference a MethodExpression instance, returned type: java.lang.String
```

JSF thinks that I'm trying to pass a method expression, but I just want to pass some string value. Is there a way to solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Must it absolutely be a POST request?

Comment: There's a navigation case for the outcome in the faces config, but I use a redirect there. The problem is that I really want to do some tests in this navigation case (<if>), that's why I can't use an h:button component.

Comment: Oh? You say that it doesn't work with `<h:button>`? How exactly does it fail?

Comment: because <h:button> has to compute the outcome first.

Comment: Can't the index string be replaced by a request scoped managed bean method that return the string index? The specs states that the action attribute must be evaluated to a public method. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserverfaces/2.2/vdldocs/facelets/h/commandButton.html

Comment: Of course I can, but I'd like to avoid this. I wouldn't like to create a bean just to do this. It seems that JSF just don't let you pass a raw string to the action method via param. You can do this directly, but not via param. I don't know, but maybe it seems that this is a shortcoming in JSF.